# When designing a model of a documentation tree, should methods that load or query this model be async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, caching, model

It's quite hard for me to formulate this question, especially that this is actually two related questions.

I am going to create a library that models API documentation of any dotnet library/package/project for later use to represent such an API documentation live without needing a tool to generate the html form of documentation or without using intelli sense.

The basis of it would be some kind of generic documentation model, modeling a namespace/assembly tree, types, type members, extension methods etc, with their associated documentation, if any. There are likely two documentation sources, but each of them works differently. One is a database with precomputed documentation. In that case, I can open the database, and lazy-query it for getting other parts of the model. A database is useful because I don't have to load documentation from diverse sources nor to hold the whole documentation tree in memory.

Second source is the compiler api. So, generally, loading the documentation tree from either c# source files if any, or assemblies + xml documentation, or nuget packages, or any combination of the above. It is probably not quite possible to do lazy loading in that case, because, for example, in case of namespace tree view, it means viewing all namespaces across all assemblies that were loaded, etc. So, that means the whole documentation tree model is in memory.

So:

- Should the method to compute the documentation from sources and assembly metadata be async, or have async versions? It potentially does a lot of IO to read c# or other source files/metadata/etc, but also does a lot of CPU work as it parses sources, reads metadata, parses xml, turns all of that into the generic model, and probably also does some more heavy stuff like computing applicatble extension methods for a given type, and that may be a bit heavy.
- Should methods in the model itself that query the model, for example, method in a type description to get all type members, be async or have async versions? In case of in memory tree I can get the answer synchronously. But in the case of documentation database/cache, I don't hold everything in memory so methods will access the database for data, so will be doing i/o.

The applications using the library will probably mostly use the database, but it is not known for sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

IMO whenever there is a lot of IO to do async should be used, regardless of how much CPU-bound work is done in parallel. Because if IO-bound  work  is done there is potential CPU-idle  time that can be used for the UI thread, so the application that might load and display the documentation model is still responsive  when loading.

For the methods that are provided by the model the answer is that it depends on how much IO work they do. If they dont  do much IO work then  there is no  need for async.

Comment: well, actually if the load operation would be async, it could be a really long running one. I mean, possibly long enough not to await on it immediately, but to display some progress or at least notification that the operation is currently in progress. So it may also be done by a long running task instead. Especially if used in an aspnet core webapp where thread pool threads are also used to process requests. When it goes to querying the model, it does disk i/o like single database queries in case of the database model.

Comment: If we talk about seconds here, i would use a simple loading indicator until the await returns. If we talk about minutes and more a prograss bar or something of course should be implemented. But that does not really affect the "async or not" discussion. What do you think is better if you do not provide an async method?

Comment: well, I am not talking about how the progress indication should work. the thing is just that I most likely would not have a gui app, but rather a webapp. So in this case it is: either sync method that loads the model and I call it directly, blocking the request, potentially for seconds... Or, sync method, but I start a long running task for this method and monitor it somehow. Or, async method, where I don't start a long running tasks, so continuations are executed on a thread pool. In this case I can still await the task directly or display some indicator and monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that the method that loads the documentation from original sources can be made async, it does not force me to await on it, so it doesn't limit my abilities to signal progress.

When it goes to the model, I am thinking about the approach where most methods for model navigation are sync and do not touch the cache, and only the top level methods in the root object of the documentation model could be async, and could load also child items. For example request to get information about some type will also load it's members, if requested. In case that decision needs to be done after getting a type object, I could introduce a method to load members and it would be async. Not sure what to do with things above types like namespaces and assemblies, but something similar, except that I think loading all data for all types at once, or all types in all namespaces, is wrong. Unless it would be loading all data except children, then it could be... not as bad, especially if some separate method for children loading would exist too.